# Doubt regarding out of gas issue for large data sets

Tags: solidity, web3js, nft, mapping, out-of-gas

Will this function cause any issues on chain how ever large the mapping becomes? Thank you.

```
mapping (uint256 => TradeHistory[]) public allTrades;
    //Trade details structure

struct TradeHistory {
    uint256 tokenId;
    uint256 price;
    uint256 date;
    address purchasedBy;
    address purchasedFrom;
}

//returns all trade history for each token
function getTradeHistoryForToken(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (TradeHistory[] memory) {
    TradeHistory[] memory trades = new TradeHistory[](allTrades[tokenId].length);
    for(uint256 i=0;i<allTrades[tokenId].length;i++){
        trades[i] = (allTrades[tokenId][i]);
    } 
    return trades;
```

Answer (score 0):

When the mapping record grows, **yes** it'll make this function unusable **because** loops that do not have a fixed number of iterations, for example, loops that depend on storage values, have to be used carefully. Due to the block gas limit, transactions can only consume a certain amount of gas. The number of iterations in a loop can grow beyond the block gas limit which can cause the complete contract to be stalled at a certain point. Additionally, using unbounded loops incurs in a lot of avoidable gas costs. Carefully test how many items at maximum you can pass to such functions to make it successful.